# No SSO Configure option in Facebook iOS App Setting

Tags: facebook, single-sign-on, facebook-ios-sdk

We are trying to create a Facebook Page for our iOS APP. But we are getting the following error - "Your iOS App does not appear to use Single Sign-On (SSO)".

In Facebook iOS App Setting page, we have enabled Facebook login, but we could not find any option to enable SSO as shown here - https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/640/

Please help us in setting up SSO in Facebook settings page.